# MariaDB JSON_ARRAYAGG output is limited to around 1MB 1048578 characters

Tags: json, mariadb

I had a MariaDB query  utilizing the new, JSON functions, the query suddenly stopped working as the number of rows increased.

When digging deeper into the problem, I've noticed that the JSON returned by `JSON_ARRAYAGG` Is invalid, to ensure its not a protocol issue, I've modified the query to this

```
SELECT date(created_at), length(JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_EXTRACT(items,'$'))) a FROM sales where 
                      Date(created_at) >= Date('2023-08-14') and Date(created_at) <= Date('2023-08-19')

2023-08-14,1048578
```

What makes the most sense is that the functions couldn't return a string grater the 1024*1024 bytes.

I've tried to search on google, and to ask the virtual assistance out there, but nothing poitned to such a restriction.

This test case shows that some MariaDB function are indeed able to handle larger strings.

```
SELECT length(repeat("AAA",1048576))
```

Any thaughts, experiances, sources on this limitation?

Thanks

This query is part of a greater subquery so it wouldn''t be streight forward, to rebuild the logic in the client language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The length is controlled by the system variable [group_concat_max_len](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/server-system-variables/#group_concat_max_len) which defaults to 1M as you have observed.

This can be changed globally, per session, or [per statement](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/set-statement/) like:

```
SET STATEMENT group_concat_max_len=10000000 SELECT ...
```

Nothing is wrong with setting it to the maximum see this post https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/197746/why-set-group-concat-max-len-below-the-maximum